# Ghost screen in the background...like water mark in my cell phone screen

Tags: hardware, cellphone, android

I'm using Moto G4 plus bought during Feb'17.I have been noting this problem for a few weeks.If I stay long in a screen for eg. a chess game, the screen stays on all the following screens in the background like a ghost or watermark.It is not caught by screenshot.it stays even if I restart the phone and disappears eventually. Can u plz explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LCD's are charge coupled devices similarly used for some dynamic memory.  Ghosting occurs when the device is aged from some condition, such that the bias conditions to reduce memory effects are no longer matched to the display characteristics.  Talk to your supplier.

Reduce display intensity for better results.  Some bright monotonic flashing bright color images have been known to discharge the residual ghosted image on full screen.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why u mention LCD...my phone's screen is LED! And it is not that much aged..just 8 months. And I'm not an engineer :) can u plz help me understand?

Comment: The LCD is still LCD just the backlight is LED. Look for sites with test images to display full saturated colours to attempt to erase the ghost.  It is a flaw perhaps caused by excessive temperature.